# How to generate project event completion timeline in PHP

Tags: php

I have many projects, each uses a Unit to complete tasks. A unit can be used in one or multiple times to complete different tasks. Even a unit can be used on the same date by different users. For an example in my below code the "unit-3" is used two times in the same date ie. `19-01-2018`, `19-01-2018`.

I want to generate a table like this:
[image: enter image description here][1]

The logic if a unit has multiple dates which are the same I want to show it just once. So for the case of `unit-3`, it has two same dates. **Even with the different date, it creates double `<td>`.**

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$units = (object) [
    (object) ['UNIT_ID' => 'unit-1', 'UNIT_DATE' => (object) ['12-01-2018']],
    (object) ['UNIT_ID' => 'unit-2', 'UNIT_DATE' => (object) ['13-01-2018', '16-01-2018']],
    (object) ['UNIT_ID' => 'unit-3', 'UNIT_DATE' => (object) ['19-01-2018', '19-01-2018']],
    (object) ['UNIT_ID' => 'unit-4', 'UNIT_DATE' => (object) ['22-01-2018']],
    (object) ['UNIT_ID' => 'unit-5', 'UNIT_DATE' => (object) ['24-01-2018']],
];

$start_date = new DateTime('10-01-2018'); //dd-mm-yyyy
$end_date = new DateTime('10-01-2018'); //dd-mm-yyyy
$end_date->modify('+15 day');
$date_range = new DatePeriod($start_date, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end_date);
?>
<table border=1 cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <th></th><!-- first column is blank -->
<?php  
        foreach ($date_range as $key => $value) {//generate table header section by date range
            echo '<th><div>'.$value->format('d-m-Y').'</div></th>';   
        }
?>
    </thead>
<tbody>
<?php
    //generate table data from array
    foreach ($units as $unit) {
        //create first column of every row based on total units
        echo '<tr><th>'.$unit->UNIT_ID.'</th>';

        //fill table body data from date range
        foreach ($date_range as $key => $value) {

            //loop through the unit date if unit date has multiple date
            foreach ($unit->UNIT_DATE as $unit_date) {

                //-----main problem is here----------
                //check if unit date is equal with date range date
                if ($value->format('d-m-Y') == $unit_date){
                    echo '<td style="background-color:red"></td>';
                } else {
                    echo '<td></td>';
                }
                //----------------------------
            }

        }
    echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: [`array_unique`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) all the way at the top where you cast in an object?

Comment: problem not only the same date, it creates double <td> with different date also.

Comment: That's a completely different question

Comment: may be I can't express it well. Let me update

Comment: You should stick with a 2-dimensional array of booleans - so that if unit X has been used on date Y you will have `$usage_by_date[Y][X] == true` and `$usage_by_unit[X][Y] == true`. You will use `$usage_by_date` to generate the dates in header, then use `$usage_by_unit` to generate rows, then for each column in the row you check whether `$usage_by_unit[current_row][current_column]` is TRUE